# Boot-up and Installation issues on my new Lenovo S20-30 Laptop

Tags: live-usb, 15.04

I own a new Lenovo S20-30 laptop which came with Windows 8.1 preinstalled with the hard drive partitioned. I want to convert this laptop to Ubuntu 15.4. with NO dual boot. I want it to be an exclusive Linux machine. This laptop can boot off the E Drive with a USB Drive.

I used a brand new Kingston 4 GB USB Drive. I followed Ubuntu installation instructions to the letter

1. I went to Pendrivelinux.com and downloaded the Universal USB Installer V1.9.5.9 to my USB Drive.
2. I went to Ubuntu and downloaded Ubuntu Linux V15.04 to my USB Drive.
3. Using The Universal USB Installer I installed Ububtu Linux 5.4 on my USB Drive.
4. My BIOS is updated to the latest BIOS from Lenovo's Website, which was posted on March 9, 2015, Filename/BIOS Version: accn22ww(v2.08&v1.1).
5. My BIOS is configured to boot from the USB Drive first
6. When I reboot the USB Drive is not recognized as a boot drive and the system still boots into Windows.

Again, I want to boot up and install Ubuntu Linux 15.04 and have the system be an exclusive LINUX machine. I have an identical Lenovo S20-30 rynning the standard Windows 8.1 and want to compare functionality and performance running the same applications on identical machines.

Has anyone installed Ubuntu Linux on a Lenovo S20-30 before?

What do I need to troubleshoot and check?

I am an experienced Windows person but new to Linux so please be gentle and don't assume I know much about Linux. That's what this is all about, I want to become Linux expert and hope I can one day soon be fully on Ubuntu Linux and never look back

---

I went back in to my BIOS and look at the configuration very carefully setting by setting. I was finally able to find the best combination of BIOS settings to get my Lenovo S20-30 to boot up from my USB Drive and Ubuntu 15.4 is fully installed now as the ONLY operating system on myS20-30.

I have painstakingly documented every BIOS setting below along with the settings I changed to sucessfully boot up from my Ubuntu Boot USB.

So now its time tolearn learn learn Ubuntu. I hope my post below proves helpful to others.

---

Here is some  additional BIOS Information

Information:
Product Name: LenovoS20-20
BIOS Version (Mostcurrent): ACCN22WW(V2.0)
EC Version:ACEC22WW(V1.1)
CPU: Intel CeleronCPU N2830 @ 2.16GHz
Windows License: WIN

Configuration:
USB XHCI Controller: Enabled
Wireless: Enabled
SATA ControllerMode: AHCI
Power Beep: Disabled
BIOS Back Flashisabled
Hotkey Mode: Enabled

Security:
Supervisor Password:Not Installed
User Password: NotInstalled
HDD Password: NotSet
Secure Boot: Enabled
Secure Boot Status:Enabled
Platform Mode: UserMode
Reset to Setup Mode: Enter
Restore FactoryKeys: Enter

Boot:
Boot Mode: UEFI is set now. The only other option to select is Legacy SupportSee the note below
USB Boot: Enabled

Note for Boot Mode:the information window states: Windows 8 or 8.1 64 Bit please useUEFI Boot Mode. Other Legacy OS please use Legacy Support Mode

Additionally I havereset the Bios to Legacy Support with the same result whenbooting up

When selecting BootMode of Legacy First I am presented with two choices for“Boot Priority”.
1. Legacy First
2. UEFI First

Withthe following note: Determine EFI Device first or LegacyDevice first. If Enable it is the EFI Device first,If Disable it is the Legacy Device First

I did cold boots with each combination selected:
UnsuccessfulBoot configuration to boot from the USB Drive: 
LegacySupport
UEFI First

Successful Bootconfiguration to boot from the USB Drive:
Legacy Support

### Legacy Device First

Comment: Is your windows is installed in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2269415) on installing Ubuntu alongside Windows in Lenovo S20-30. You can refer this link to get your USB booted.

To completely remove windows and install Ubuntu, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) or [this](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-completely-wipe-windows-8-and-install-linux/1416) thread and have a look at the Official [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) on UEFI firmware. After you have understood what you have to do, then boot from live cd/USB and select `Use the Entire Disk option` to install Ubuntu over windows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I didn't understood what you meant by: "This laptop can boot off the E Drive with a USB Drive".
Doesn't matter.

1. I don't know for sure why Ubuntu recommend to use `Universal USB Installer`, it didn't work for my Lenovo Y580 as well. UNetbootin might not work either, assuming you have UEFI/GPT machine since Windows 8.1 was preinstalled. Use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) instead.
2. You shouldn't download ISO to USB but to HDD. I guess you misspelled that.
3. To use Rufus firs you should select ISO and then adjust other settings(UEFI/GPT), otherwise it wil reset your options(small bug in software).
4. Again, I don't believe you have BIOS rather UEFI. Enable USB boot and set order to first boot from USB. If you considering don't use `Legacy mode` no need for that.

So, your bootabe USB is set to go. You can use it in `Live mode`, before installation, to check if your devices are working properly: ethernet, bluetooth, WiFi...If not look around this site for an answer.You won't be disappointed because Ubuntu is much lighter on resources than Windows.

And since you are now to askubuntu , do check if anyone else has post a similar question first.